# How can I prevent anonymous users from seeing unapproved blog comments?

Tags: blog, anonymous-authentication

Anonymous users are able to post a blog comment, but are able to see unapproved comments that are simply draft items on the Comments list.  This seems like a bug that MS simply has not addressed yet.

We've tried the following configuration unsuccessfully -

1. Anonymous Permission

   - Site Level = Entire Website
   - Posts = View Items
   - Comments = Add Items, View Items
2. Comments List (Advanced Settings)

   - Read Access = Read All Items
   - Create and Edit Access = Create and Edit Items that were created by the user
3. Versioning Settings

   - Require Content Approval for submitted items = Yes
   - Who should see draft items in the list = only users who can approve items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the configuration changes I described in my question, to enable the moderation of anonymous comments while at the same time preventing anonymous users from seeing each others unmoderated comments, I had to create a custom list event receiver.  The ModerationEventReceiver class from SPAdrian's [Office 365 Anonymous Access Manager Sandbox Solution](http://anonymous365.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/16372#163948) was very helpful.

I've included the ItemAdded and ItemUpdated events from my event receiver below...

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.ItemAdded(properties);
    // Use elevated privileges
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
    {
        using (SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite(properties.Web.Site.ID))
        {
            using (SPWeb elevatedWeb = elevatedSite.AllWebs[properties.RelativeWebUrl])  // Removing permissions on root site since we're in web provisioned and in the subsite
            {
                elevatedWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                SPList elevatedList = elevatedWeb.Lists[properties.List.ID];
                SPListItem elevatedListItem = elevatedList.GetItemById(properties.ListItemId);

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(properties.UserLoginName)
                    && elevatedList != null
                    && elevatedList.RootFolder != null)
                {
                    EventFiringEnabled = false;
                    elevatedListItem.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
                    EventFiringEnabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

/// <summary>
/// An item was updated
/// </summary>
public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    // Use elevated privileges
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
    {
        using (SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite(properties.Web.Site.ID))
        {
            using (SPWeb elevatedWeb = elevatedSite.AllWebs[properties.RelativeWebUrl])  // Removing permissions on root site since we're in web provisioned and in the subsite
            {
                elevatedWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                SPList elevatedList = elevatedWeb.Lists[properties.List.ID];
                SPListItem elevatedListItem = elevatedList.GetItemById(properties.ListItemId);

                if (elevatedList != null
                    && elevatedList.RootFolder != null)
                {
                    base.ItemUpdated(properties);
                    EventFiringEnabled = false;
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(properties.UserLoginName))
                    {
                        //Reset access for anonymous users
                        elevatedListItem.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Test if someone has approved and reset inheritance
                        if (elevatedListItem.ModerationInformation.Status == SPModerationStatusType.Approved)
                        {
                            elevatedListItem.ResetRoleInheritance();
                        }
                    }
                    EventFiringEnabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```